# Pigenhole Principle Problem

Tags: proof-writing

I am doing some hw but I cannot figure out this one. Hint: it is part of a pigeonhole principle.

**Question:**  Prove that if $a$ is a natural number, then there exist two unequal natural numbers $k$ and $l$ for which $a^k - a^l$ is divisible by 10.

Any help much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the problem, I intended it to be $a^k - a^l$.

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are only ten possible values for $a^k\bmod10$ for all natural numbers $a$, but infinitely possible values for $k$.

Comment: Use `\bmod` for the binary operation; that way you get the right spacing.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for that. I have been using \mod for so long.